# Spring Security OAuth2 with iOS app for Apple or Google Sign In

Tags: swift, spring-security, oauth-2.0, apple-sign-in

My team and I are currently developing an iOS app that connects to our Spring Boot backend, unfortunately there is little to no documentation online on how to manage authentication between the two.

Here is what we aim to achieve:

- User opens app and is prompted to sign in with Apple.
- App then sends some sort of token that can be used to retrieve the users email to the backend with all requests.
- Backend then verifies email using token with each request.

Is this possible to do? If so, a resource on how to do it would be greatly appreciated! I have spent hours looking online to figure out how to do this with not much out there.

Comment: Here is a great documentation from apple https://developer.apple.com/documentation/sign_in_with_apple/sign_in_with_apple_rest_api